# Xpath filter to find specific value in nested blocks

Tags: xml, xpath, filtering

I inherited a legacy system with an XPath filter which is not my strong side.

Example XML (which I cannot change):

```
<bill>
    <header>
       <no>1234</no>
    </header>
    <details>
       <company>C1009</company>
       <lineNo>1</lineNo>
       <amount>770.50</lineNo>
    </details>
    <details>
       <company>C1009</company>
       <lineNo>2</lineNo>
       <amount>1050.50</lineNo>
    </details>
</bill>
```

I need a function to find a specific company number for each bill-xml. In this case it is company 1009. The function just needs to return a true/false (empty or found). How to solve this?

There is already a filter for another purpose in the system which successfully finds a field but I cannot get it to work with the multiple  lines:

```
/*[local-name() = 'details']/*[local-name()='company' and contains(text(),'C1009')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The next XPath will match all `<details>` elements with an element `<company>` which has a value that contains the text 1009:

```
/bill/details[contains(company, '1009')]
```

If you don't want to match on a part of the text, but you know the exact value in `<company>` element, you can use:

```
/bill/details[company = 'C1009']
```

Also note that `local-name()` can be used, but if there are no namespaces, you can use the XPath as I described. Otherwise you can use `local-name()` or declare the namespace and use that prefix.